# Problem with normals / smooth shading ( visible triangles on flat surface )

Tags: modeling, normals

I'm modeling a pistol and I've come across this weird problem with shading ( or normals, I don't know what is going on ).

The triangles are showing on flat surface. I search whole internet and haven't found a solution yet....

[image]

[image]

I know there are ngons ( I used boolean ) but is there any solution other than not using ngons?

Comment: blend file : https://files.fm/u/2d9pmmee

Comment: You have bad topology caused by NGons. Never use Booleans, see http://topologyguides.com

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's the n-gons.  One workaround is to select the edges that you want be sharp, hit Ctrl-E, click "Mark Sharp", and then enable "auto-smooth" under the mesh data.
Hope that helps!